# Preselect Check box with Rails Simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, checkbox

I'm using [Simple_Form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) with Rails 3 and it's great. I have a simple question. I can create a check box using `f.input` if the type is boolean behind the scenes. However, I would like it to be preselected as true.

Is there a way to do this via the view?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

the best way would be to set the default value in your model, something like

```
create_table :my_table do |t|
  ...
  t.boolean :my_boolean, :default => true
  ...
end
```

which `simple_form` will pick up on, and set the checkbox to be checked by default.

A simpler way is to do it as Dave says, and just force the value to 1, but if a validation fails, and you display the form again, it will still be checked, regardless of how it looked when the form was submitted.

Comment: actually this works but it involves something more with a default value on the database. I think the best option here is to work only on client side selecting the value through :input_html => { :checked => true }

Comment: This is a better answer.

Answer (score 105):

If you don't want to, or cannot update your migration to do 'PerfectlyNormal's answer, then you can add the following to the end of your f.input:

```
:input_html => { :checked => true }
```

So, it would become:

```
= f.input :some_flag, :input_html => { :checked => true }
```

Comment: if the value of the form does not exist on the database this is the best solution...

Answer (score 14):

It Worked for me which **checks only one checkbox** with value of **"None"**

```
<%= f.input :notify, label: "Notification", as: :check_boxes, collection: ["None", "Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly", "Quarterly", "Yearly"], :item_wrapper_class => 'inline', :checked => ["None", true] %>
```

Comment: For :checked => ["None", true], true is not needed as :checked looks for the HTML input element with value within the provided array. Ignoring true works fine.


```<%= f.input :notify, label: "Notification", as: :check_boxes, collection: ["None", "Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly", "Quarterly", "Yearly"], :item_wrapper_class => 'inline', :checked => ["None"] %>```

Answer (score 3):

I just stumbled over this post and what worked for me is similar to the latest answer - but shorter. Just initialize the Object with the wished setting:

```
def new
  Object.new(my_boolean: true)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the rail way to do this would be to set the value of the attribute in the controller:

@some_object.some_flag = 1

Comment: I think most folks would say this logic belongs in the model.

Comment: I would say, it depends. Strong parameters are defined in the controller. Hence the value of your flag can depend on the current context. ?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
= f.input :some_flag, :input_html => { :value => '1' }
```

Comment: -1 as would really mess up any database form for edit so this is really not good advice.

Comment: Really? Dude asked how to set it in the view. Where did it say he was ever going to be editing it?

Comment: Hi Dave, in rails the view represents the front end html shown in the browser.  When Drew says "if the type is boolean behind the scenes" that would seem to imply that this is going against an active record model and the use of a checkbox against any active record model would seem to imply that he wishes to edit/update that attribute.  I will refrain from downvoting you however as that seems a bit petty.

Comment: You should use `input_html: { checked: true }`

Answer (score 1):

If you do the following, as in the highest rated answer (and as noted by @PerfectlyNormal) you are essentially hard-coding the state for *every page load*:

```
= f.input :some_flag, :input_html => { :checked => true } # don't do this
```

If you are using Rails-style server validation, this will have the unintended side effect of resetting the user's choice when validation fails.

Defaulting it in the model is ideal if the default value is static. In some cases though, the default value is driven by some business rule, so setting it at runtime is desired. For example, in my case, I wanted to default a checkbox to true, but only for certain types of organizations.

What you want is to default the value *only when it is not already set*, otherwise use the user-selected value. Here's how I handled this:

```
- is_checked = @org.is_special.nil? ? true : @org.is_special?
= f.input :some_flag, :input_html => { :checked => is_checked }
```

Answer (score -1):

For Rails 6+, you can simply do:

```
<%= f.check_box :remember_me,  checked: true %>
```