# Rails simple form checkbox default to true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

How do I make a simple for boolean checkbox default to true?

`assign_client` is a boolean field.

I tried these:

```
<%= f.input :assign_client, :label => 'Charge Client?', :true %>
<%= f.input :assign_client, :label => 'Charge Client?', :value => :true %>
<%= f.input :assign_client, :label => 'Charge Client?', :value => 1 %>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: a simple `f.input :assign_client, :label => 'Charge Client?', :value => true` should do it (remember that you have to check the checkbox to pass the params[:assign_client]'s value)

Comment: MrYoshiji - thanks for the help!  If I entered what you said, the checkbox is not checked when the form is displayed. I'm not sure what you meant by your comment in parens.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you should add `input_html`:

```
<%= f.input :assign_client, :label => 'Charge Client?', :input_html => { :checked => true }
```

[proof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116415/preselect-check-box-with-rails-simple-form)

Comment: <%= f.input :assign_client, :label => 'Charge Client?', as: boolean, :input_html => { :checked => true } %> if the field is attr_accessor.

Comment: But it doesn't prepopulate value in case of errors in forms.

Answer (score 3):

Your second one will work fine just remove the `:` so it's a boolean value rather than a symbol.

```
<%= f.input :assign_client, :label => 'Charge Client?', :value => true %>
```